Can I play different audios to different external monitors, at the same time?
I have a MacBook Pro 13" mid-2015, which has an HDMI port and two Thunderbolt 2 ports. If I connect two external monitors, one via HDMI and the other one via Thunderbolt 2, and those monitors have speakers, can I play different video and sounds on each of them at the same time, using the extended display mode?

Not an answer because I don't know if it works on Mac, but Voicemeeter works fantastically on Windows for this.

Do you have a specific requirement on the app you want/need to use? Some allow you to select the output device, others will only use the system default.

@jcaron no specific need, just something universal.

I’m fairly certain the answer is no here.
macOS (and iOS and iPadOS) can mix multiple sources into one output and then send that one output to multiple speakers (with AirPlay) but not manage two entirely distinct audio streams to the two displays.

Sad. No third-party app can help me?

You can create virtual devices that contain multiple outputs in Audio MIDI Setup.app; but as you say, you can't separate the content.

Not anything I can recall @PineCode but if my answer (or any answer) is wrong on the internet it tends to shake out all the good answers very rapidly. Rogue Amoeba does the best work in this space and I can’t see anyone open sourcing as good a tool as they have built over two decades plus doing sound on Apple OS.

That seems a bit strong. Many apps allow you to select which input and output you want to use for audio and video (FaceTime, Teams, Zoom, etc. allow this for instance). What you select at the macOS level is just a default, and that's what apps which do not have specific controls will use.

Have you seen one that breaks out multiple displays as speakers @jcaron I’d be happy to learn I’m wrong and this exists like all the other audio options. I’m not saying it’s a good implementation, just reporting the facts as I know them.

@bmike I don't have multiple displays at hand, but at least I've regularly seen the "built-in Speakers" (and headphones separately if any are connected) and whatever display (with the same of the display) as separate choices. Check VLC -> Audio -> Audio device for instance.

It's possible to do it using 3rd party app Soundsource, however only per app basis (so no two separate Youtube videos in Safari etc.). It's a bit pricey because it's ~48$, but it has also some other useful features.


But I can play separate YouTube videos using, for example, Chrome and Firefox together, right? Do you know of FOSS alternatives?

It will require an amazing amount of skill and passion to do what Rogue Ameoba does and then release it open source @PineCode

@bmike thanks for the vision.
